# Printing all combinations, python

Tags: python, combinations

say I have 3 different variables and each has 2 possible values, so in total I have 8 different combinations. Is there a python library function, or an algorithm that I can use to print all possible combinations?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python code to pick out all possible combinations from a list?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/python-code-to-pick-out-all-possible-combinations-from-a-list)

Comment: @MattFenwick: No, this is not a combinations problem, rather it's the product the OP is looking for.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists-in-python)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you're looking for [product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product):

```
a = [1, 2]
b = [100, 200]
c = [1000, 2000]

import itertools
for p in itertools.product(a, b, c):
    print p
```

prints:

```
(1, 100, 1000)
(1, 100, 2000)
(1, 200, 1000)
(1, 200, 2000)
(2, 100, 1000)
(2, 100, 2000)
(2, 200, 1000)
(2, 200, 2000)
```

Answer (score 1):

And the true one function here is [itertools.product](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product)